# RegExp exec not working in for loop snippet - Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, debugging

Can someone help check this snippet? I'm just looping on array but the last item return false or null even its matches the pattern.

```
let texts = ["Invoice_001_1", "Invoice_001_2"];
var regTest = /(([a-zA-Z 0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)$|[a-zA-Z ]+_([0-9]+)$)/gi;

for(var x=0; x<texts.length; x++) {
    console.log(texts[x]);
    var matchReg = regTest.exec(texts[x]);
    console.log(matchReg);
}
```

[JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7L0k3mpu/1/)

Comment: to put it simply: never ever use `regex.exec` in javascript. It's broken. Use `string.match` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when using `/g`, js has a little gotcha, in that it tells the regexp to keep the index of the last match.The fix is to manually reset the index:

```js
let texts = ["Invoice_001_1", "Invoice_001_2"];
var regTest = /(([a-zA-Z 0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)$|[a-zA-Z ]+_([0-9]+)$)/gi;

for(var x=0; x<texts.length; x++) {
        console.log(texts[x]);
        var matchReg = regTest.exec(texts[x]);
    console.log(matchReg);
    regTest.lastIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Or to not use `/g` at all, it is not needed in this case